# Node.js file upload on Windows

Tags: string, node.js, file-upload, encoding

I have encountered a problem with a fileupload using node.js and formidable.

The File is being uploaded correctly, but when it's name is changed back to its original one, using this command:

```
fs.renameSync("./" + files['upload-file'].path, "./u/" + files['upload-file'].name);
```

The Problem which arises is the following: if the Filename contains some characters like ä ö ü, they are not written to the filesytem in that way. I guess the problem is the encoding of the new Filename, but I have no idea how I can change it.

As Suggested, here is some additional info:
The name of the file is this one: 07 Zerstören.mp3
The name of the file on the filesytem is this one: 07 Zerst�ren.mp3

Comment: You can convert encodings using [Iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv) if it's your problem.

Comment: Show your `files['upload-file']` object and resulting filename if you need more help.

Comment: It's definitely an encoding issue, but I cant figure out the root of this problem.

Comment: Works fine for me on Windows 7 x64, Node 0.8.16.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't be using `renameSync` -- it blocks your server from doing anything else until the filesystem call completes.